# Why can't I install kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib using pip?

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I run a `pyenv` to use python 3.5.2 and `venv` to manage my packages. I can successfully install the `graph` flower from github, but not the `garden.matplotlib` flower.

This command works fine:

```
 .venv/bin/python3 -m pip install https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph/archive/master.zip
```

while this one downloads, but fails installation:

```
.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib/archive/master.zip
```

How can I solve this? I need to develop the code on my Mac and run it on a raspberry pi afterwards.

pip 19.2.2 (for this environment)

[image: Terminal output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph repo has the necessary code to be installable via pip, while the garden.matplotlib repo does not.

I think the matplotlib one may be waiting to be converted to a new-style garden flower, which is designed to be pip-installable.

A workaround would be to just copy the matplotlib one into your app dir and import from there.

Comment: Ahhh... But is there anyway to make it easy to install on another computer then? I have to deploy this code to several raspberry pi's, and manually handling the import on each of them is a bit of a drag. I thought of using the freeze and install -r capability of pip to help me out with that. Maybe I should containerize instead?

Comment: If I was feeling lazy I would just copy the repository around, that's pretty trivial. The better solution would be to add pip support to the repository, there is a guide for this [here](https://kivy-garden.github.io/#guideformigratingflowersfromlegacystructure). We'd be happy to merge these changes into the official garden.matplotlib repository if you'd like to contribute them.